Error Drupal SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint
I have an error after migrating Drupal database from MySQL to PostgresSQL. All works fine, but when I want to add a node (all types), an error fires:
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "" LINE 2: WHERE "nid" = '' ^: DELETE FROM "node_field_data" WHERE "nid" = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 817 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
This error appears after pushing the "create" button in new node page.
I'm going crazy and can't figure it out.
Drupal version is 10.3.2
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

An empty string '' is indeed an invalid big integer.
